# I'm just start with the subject of partial-fractions and I get stuck in this excercise.

Tags: integration, partial-fractions, substitution

I have:

$$\int \frac{1}{x^3-1} dx$$

So...I reach this point, and then I just don´t know how to continue:

$$\frac{1}{3}\ln|x-1|- \frac{1}{3}\int \frac{x+2}{x^2+x+1} dx$$

The answer should be easy, but I don´t know how to get it. Please step by step.

Comment: Not really; I'd say the answer should be quite ugly. Do you know how to integrate $1\over x^2+1$? What about $x\over x^2+1$? Now you'll have to apply both.

Comment: My method of the integration for the examples that you mention, doesn´t really help me in this particular case.

Comment: Especially in the missing integral .

Comment: Too bad, because it should. Let's start with $\int{dx\over x^2+x+1}$; what would become of it if we change to the new variable $t=x+{1\over2}$? Well, or look at the answer by @MarioG.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**
Since $x^2+x+1=\left(x+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2+\frac{3}{4}$ we have
\begin{align}
\int\frac{x+2}{x^2+x+1}\,dx&=\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{2x+4}{x^2+x+1}\,dx\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{2x+1+3}{x^2+x+1}\,dx\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{2x+1}{x^2+x+1}\,dx+\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{3}{x^2+x+1}\,dx\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\ln\left(x^2+x+1\right)+\frac{3}{2}\int\frac{dx}{\left(x+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2+\frac{3}{4}}\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\ln\left(x^2+x+1\right)+\frac{3}{2}\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}\arctan\left(\frac{x+\frac{1}{2}}{\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}}\right)+c\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\ln\left(x^2+x+1\right)+\sqrt{3}\arctan\left(\frac{2x+1}{\sqrt{3}}\right)+c
\end{align}

Comment: Yes, I just did that. Actually I put the line where is dificult for me.

Comment: @user265955: I have added some details, please can you review?

Comment: why the 2x+1. Where do you get it?

Comment: Why don't you think about it for a minute? Don't expect every last detail to be spoonfed to you. Peace.

Comment: Why the 2x+1, really? What else could it be that would make the whole thing integrate nicely?

Comment: I´m only want to learn man and I don´t really see it.  Don´t sacrifice me for that

Comment: @user265955 Integrands that contain fractions with irreducible quadratic polynomials in the denominator which can be handled as a sum of two terms: one which integral is a logarithm and another one, which can be integrated by completing the square. But you also can use tables or some tricky sustitution to get the result faster. Here, by irreducible I mean that there are no factors with real coefficients.

Comment: Thanks man. That´s all I need.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**
$$\int\frac{\mathrm d\mkern1mu x}{x^2+a^2}=\frac1a\arctan\frac xa.$$